# Upload file to 'my documents(SkyDrive)' of user's 'mysite' from sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, cross-domain, sharepoint-2013

My sharepoint online site url is `https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecoll` , and the 'my site' url of my account is `https://sitename-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myusername`
the  my documents url in 'my site' is `https://sitename-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myusername/Documents`

Now I'm tring to upload documents to 'my site' document library using csom / REST. The upload form will be in `https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecoll` , since both are different domains the upload is not working(I'm able to upload to Document libraries in the current sitecollection). I tried approaches using CSOM, REST, REST with crossdomain library (SP.RequestExecutor.js) none of them are working.

In CSOM I created context by using

`var clientcontext = new SP.ClientContext(mysiteurl);`

-then im getting error like 'app web not deployed on this server'. (im using webpart not app part)

I used REST and REST with cross domain library.-then I was getting forbidden error.
the same code is working if I upload to the current site document libraries.

How can I upload file to 'my site' from the site collection page using JavaScript ?

Comment: Did you ever get this? I'm being told you need implement a cross domain policy file on a SharePoint Document Library

Comment: Yes i get this. I created an App and deployed it into app catalog and from there i did batch deployment to my Site(optional) . if we deploy app using development tools like VS. the app ask you for permissions but the validation will not be done. So I published app (.app) and i uploaded .app file to app catalog. and in app catalog site contents i added app, and i used that app. If you deploy the directly to site using VS it cannot upload file to SkyDrive. I'm using SharePoint online.